# How to find the index position of items in a pandas list which satisfy a certain condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I find the index position of items in a list which satisfy a certain condition?
Like suppose, I have a list like:

```
myList = [0, 100, 335, 240, 300, 450, 80, 500, 200]
```

And the condition is to find out the position of all elements within myList which lie between 0 and 300 (both inclusive).
I am expecting the output as:

```
output = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8]
```

How can I do this in pandas?

Also, how to find out the index of the maximum element in the subset of elements which satisfy the condition? Like, in the above case, out of the elements which satisfy the given condition 300 is the maximum and its index is 4. So, need to retrieve its index.

I have been trying many ways but not getting the desired result. Please help, I am new to the programming world.

Comment: How is ```myList``` in ```pandas```? Is it a column, or it's supposed to be a ```list``` and not ```pandas```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 100, 335, 240, 300, 450, 80, 500, 200]})
>>> index = list(df[(df.a >= 0) & (df.a <= 300)].index)
>>> df.loc[index,].idxmax()
a    4
dtype: int64
```

or using the list,

```py
>>> l = [0, 100, 335, 240, 300, 450, 80, 500, 200]
>>> index = [(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(l) if v >= 0 and v <= 300]
>>> [t[0] for t in index]
[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8]
>>> sorted(index, key=lambda x: x[1])[-1][0]
4
```

As `Grzegorz Skibinski` says, if we use numpy to get rid of many computations,

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = [0, 100, 335, 240, 300, 450, 80, 500, 200]
>>> index = np.array([[i, v] for i, v in enumerate(l) if v >= 0 and v <= 300])
>>> index[:,0]
array([0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8])
>>> index[index.argmax(0)[1]][0]
4
```

Comment: Ok, seriously rewriting it to ```numpy``` would save you a lot of computations. Rewriting your example: ```index = np.array([[i, v] for i, v in enumerate(l) if v >= 0 and v <= 300])
index[:,0]
index[index.argmax(0)[1]][0]```

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right! I added to my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy` for that purpose:

```py
import numpy as np
myList =np.array( [0, 100, 335, 240, 300, 450, 80, 500, 200])

res=np.where((myList>=0)&(myList<=300))[0]

print(res)
###and to get maximum:

res2=res[myList[res].argmax()]

print(res2)
```

Output:

```py
[0 1 3 4 6 8]
4

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Hi..Thankyou for your help. But i need to retrieve the index of the maximum element and not the max element itself. Like in myList max element between 0 & 300 is 300 which lies at 4th position. So i need 4 as o/p and not 300. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can look for your question.

Comment: `E.Zeytinci` Thank you for your update. It worked like a charm. How can I modify this code to find the index of the min element in the subset?

Comment: `E.Zeytinci` I got it :) ... just added `reverse=True`

Answer (score 0):

This is `between` in pandas:

```
myList = [0, 100, 335, 240, 300, 450, 80, 500, 200]
s= pd.Series(myList)
s.index[s.between(0,300)]
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8], dtype='int64')
```